# Loop of console.log in nodejs

Tags: node.js, console.log

My MCVE is the following

```
var i = 0;
for(;;)
    console.log(i++)
```

When I do this, at a certain moment, my `nodejs` just stops printing stuff, giving me an output that looks like this

```
[...]
684665
684666
684667
```

And then, I got this :

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

   69097 ms: Scavenge 1397.2 (1456.7) -> 1397.2 (1456.7) MB, 0.8 / 0 ms (+ 1.7 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
   70462 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.2 (1456.7) -> 1396.0 (1456.7) MB, 1364.9 / 0 ms (+ 2.8 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.7 ms) [last resort gc].
   71833 ms: Mark-sweep 1396.0 (1456.7) -> 1397.1 (1456.7) MB, 1370.2 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0xcdf79d37399 <JS Object>
    1: formatPrimitive(aka formatPrimitive) [util.js:~411] [pc=0x634d9f4113f] (this=0xcdf79d04131 <undefined>,ctx=0x17b18f4d561 <an Object with map 0x32fd25043ef9>,value=16248021)
    2: formatValue(aka formatValue) [util.js:223] [pc=0x634d9f1fdbb] (this=0xcdf79d04131 <undefined>,ctx=0x17b18f4d561 <an Object with map 0x32fd25043ef9>,value=16248021,recurseTimes=2)
    3: inspect(aka inspect) [uti...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
[1]    19446 abort (core dumped)  node
```

I was wondering, what can `console.log` do that could lead to an out of memory error ?

Comment: I think it's overflowing a buffer and it must be flushed

Comment: @Chris I edited my post, it was not a flush problem

Comment: Might be worth opening a ticket on the [NodeJS repository](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues) link to this question.

Comment: how large does the `i` grow bevor this happens?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha thanks for the suggestion. I opened the issue [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3524)

Comment: @gapvision I just tried. It crash when the process can't have more RAM. On my machine, it crash around 3Gb. When you execute the loop, the process take more and more RAM until it crash.

Comment: @Magus yes, same here, good to know that it's not only on my machine, thanks for testing it

Comment: Very weird, this operation should be processor bound not memory bound, it will be interesting to know why memory grows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After opening an issue on the nodejs repository, I got the [following answer](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3524#issuecomment-151088049) :

> It's expected behavior: **console.log is asynchronous**, the memory associated with each call cannot be reclaimed until the next tick of the event loop. In your example that next tick never happens because of the infinite loop. If you rewrite your example to a callback-driven approach, it keeps running forever:
>
> ```
>  let i = 0;
>  const next = () => process.stdout.write(`${i++}\n`, next);
>  next();
> ```

Answer (score 7):

According to this discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/KtONbpVV68U

Every time you call `console.log` (or an other logging method), the console object will allocate some memory. This memory will be free by the garbage collector on its next tick. But if you have a too big loop, the next tick never come.

But i tested this :

```
setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}, 10000)
```

According to the google group discussion, between each interval, NodeJS garbage collector should free the allocated memory by the console.log. But it is not. Every time the loop is running, my process take more RAM.

I also tested this :

```
var fs = require('fs')
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
var errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
var logger = new console.Console(output, errorOutput);

var i = 0;
for (;;) {
    logger.log(i++);
}
```

The behavior is the same. The process take more and more RAM until it crash (because nore more RAM is available). And the file `stdout.log` is always empty.

Finally, i tested this :

```
var fs = require('fs')
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
var errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
var logger = new console.Console(output, errorOutput);

setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        logger.log(i);
    }
}, 5000)
```

This example is interesting. Because between each interval, `stdout.log` is written (the lines are appended to the file) and the RAM reclaimed by the process doesn't grow. Between each interval the garbage collector do its works.

I think the console object does not handle well the buffer. But it is still weird. If you use the standard output (with just a `console.log`), it's look the console object keep in memory everthing printed so far. And it is never cleanse. And if you use a file ouput, everything works fine (except if you write it in an infinity loop, of course).

Maybe it's because of the NodeJS version, i'm working with a NodeJS 0.12.7

Comment: Your first `setInterval` example doesn't seem to overload my RAM, maybe because of my version (4.2.1).

Comment: How do I exit the foor loop? I have more code to be executed, but it never gets to it since the setInterval keeps firing.

Answer (score 1):

See more details in discussion at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11568

Also, as descibed in documentation the console is **synchronous** when stdout redirected to a file. But described behavior still also reproduced in this case.

An infinite loop with `console.log()` output redirected to a file does not crash Node v4.x but crash Node v6.
This is seems like a bug introduced in v6.

As a temporary workaround it is possible to use [console-sync](https://github.com/litmit/console-sync) patch.